# how to set autoincrement value to another column in table in yii2 model

Tags: yii2, yii2-model

I have form with two input fields like name,userid and the table columns are id(autoincrement,name,userid). If i save a record, the auto increment value of id will save in a column of userid. I have used a trigger for this, But this is not suitable because i'm using more than 10 table, So i need to write trigger for all the table.

So suggest me how to do this in yii2 model without write trigger.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a custom autoincrement field. You can override `beforeSave` function in your model.

```
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function beforeSave($insert)
{
    if (parent::beforeSave($insert)) {
        if(!$this->id)
        {
            $this->id = yourFunctionToCreateAutoincrementValue();
        }
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```